# using guid in ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I search a lot,but didn't find any solution. I have a product table and here ProductID is guid. And in index.cshtml I have a edit link

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit","Edit","Admin",new{id=i.ProductID})
```

When I click link, url like it

```
http://localhost:5546/Admin/Edit?Length=5
```

And I get following error

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Guid' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Edit(System.Guid)' in 'RiotBooks.Controllers.AdminController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
```

Parameter name: parameters
How to I solve it?

Comment: show your controller code

Comment: public ActionResult Edit(Guid id)
        {
            var product = unitOfWork.ProductRepository.GetByID(id);
           return View(product);
        }

Answer (score 3):

You're using the wrong overload of ActionLink.

The one you're calling there is [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124%28v=vs.118%29.aspx):

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    Object routeValues,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

but you really want to be calling [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972%28v=vs.118%29.aspx):

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    Object routeValues,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

So just change your call to

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit","Edit","Admin",new{id=i.ProductID}, null)
```

and you'll be good.

For the record, the tip off to me was that `?Length=5` comes from the fact that the `string` "Admin" being passed into the routeValues parameter has only one property on it (`Length`) and the length of that `string` is 5.